# Log and monitor detailed access in my windows client (RDP or SMB or etc)

Tags: windows, logging, rdp, smb, computer-forensics

I am using windows Os in my office. this is my network administrator policy that every body have SMB open and RDP access.
I want to know who and when accessed my PC via RDP or smb share. 
Can i find this log in my windows event log?
Is there any GUI based tools that i can analyze access logs?
I am not advanced user, is there any simple tool to log analyzing in windows?

Best regard.

Answer (score 0):

> Can i find this log in my windows event log?

Yes you can ... go take a look at **Operational** for RDP logs

`Computer management->Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Microsoft->TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager->Operational`

For SMB-Connections take a look here https://superuser.com/questions/1181937/find-events-for-connections-to-a-shared-drive-in-the-windows-event-log